# Google Firebase Function Firebase auth onCreate event handler - failed to configure trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to add a Firebase Authentication onCreate user event handler to insert user into Google Cloud SQL database. I got it to work successfully locally with the database public IP, and it successfully adds rows to the SQL database.

I ran `firebase deploy -P gircapp2` and this is what I got from the google cloud function logs:

```js
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 13,
      "message": "Failed to configure trigger providers/firebase.auth/eventTypes/user.create@firebaseauth.googleapis.com (__gcf__.us-central1.createGircUser)"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "gircapptest@gmail.com"
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.UpdateFunction",
    "resourceName": "projects/gircapp2/locations/us-central1/functions/createGircUser"
  },
  "insertId": "46dje7cgk6",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "createGircUser",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "gircapp2"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2021-02-02T19:01:54.537912Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/gircapp2/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "operation": {
    "id": "operations/Z2lyY2FwcDIvdXMtY2VudHJhbDEvY3JlYXRlR2lyY1VzZXIvQU82VHdMQkROTUE",
    "producer": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2021-02-02T19:01:54.579884326Z"
}
```

Here is my index.js, which works locally and updates successfully google cloud SQL database:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { Sequelize, Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize')
const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager')

var password = ""

const name = 'projects/gircapp2/secrets/postgrespassword/versions/latest';

// Instantiates a client
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

async function accessSecretVersion() {
  const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
    name: name,
  });

  // Extract the payload as a string.
  const payload = version.payload.data.toString();

  password = payload
}

// run this in google functions shell emulator to make a user:
// firebase functions:shell
// firebase > createGircUser({uid: "654321"}) 

class User extends Model {}

exports.createGircUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((firebaseuser) => {
(async () => {

    const user = 'postgres'
    const host = 'gircapp2:us-central1:gircpostgres'
    const database = 'postgres'
    const port = '5432'

    await accessSecretVersion();

    const sequelize = await new Sequelize(database, user, password, {
        host,
        port,
        dialect: 'postgres',
        logging: false
      })

    await User.init({
        userId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        speciality: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        degree: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        verified: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
        }
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: "user",
        timestamps: true,
    })

    const userId = firebaseuser.uid

    await User.sync({force: false}).then(() => {
        // users table created
        return User.create({
          userId: userId,
          verified: false,
        });
      });

})()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that Firebase Auth is not yet enabled on your project because you are passing `uid` through a test environment to trigger the event instead of creating a new email on Firebase Console.

Fix it by going to Firebase Console > Firebase Authentication and set up Sign-In method. On your case, you can enable email or a federated identity provider (ex. Google):

[image]

Afterwards, redeploy your function then add user on the Firebase Console.

---

As an addition, when trying to connect to a Cloud SQL instance using Cloud Functions, you're supposed to connect [with Unix Sockets](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#connecting_to) by default. With your current code, you will encounter "Not Found" runtime error. You should fix it by changing your `host` to:

```
const host = '/cloudsql/gircapp2:us-central1:gircpostgres'
```